# React Router Link changing css

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, router

For some reason the React Router Link is significantly changing my css. Is there a way I can remove any styling impact from the Link?

Without Link:

[image]

With Link:
[image]

This is the code for the Link. It has no style features.

````
```
<Link to={`/link/${item.id}`}>
```
````

style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}

Answer (score 0):

Use this Npm : [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-bootstrap](https://import%20%7B%20LinkContainer%20%7D%20from%20%27react-router-bootstrap%27%20%3CLinkContainer%20to=%22/foo/bar%22%3E%20%20%20%3CButton%3EFoo%3C/Button%3E%20%3C/LinkContainer%3E)

```
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

<LinkContainer to="/foo/bar">
  <Button>Foo</Button>
</LinkContainer>
```

This will work same as the link without effecting your css

Answer (score 0):

Since Link get's transpiled to an `<a>`, you can use css to style `<a>` all  and change all links color to white:

```
a {
  color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
   color: #00F
}
```

Or add a `.link` class to each `Link`:

```
<Link to="/" className="link" />
...

.link {
  color: #FFF;
}
.link:hover {
   color: #00F
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, adding css to the inside of the Link item changed the formatting. I copied the css of the images from what they previously were to the styling of the image inside the link and it looks the same.